# full screen background htm5 mobile

Tags: html, css

I have created a full screen background which seems to fit all browsers but when checking on a mobile device it displays like this.

This is the css I have used

```
   @font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('LeagueGothic-Regular_0.otf')
}


html {   
background: url(splash.png) no-repeat center center fixed;   
-webkit-background-size: cover;   
-moz-background-size: cover;   
-o-background-size: cover;   
background-size: cover; 
text-align:center;
}
#logo {
margin:0 auto;
}

#main {
margin:0 auto;
width:1200px;

}

p {
font-family:myFirstFont;
color:white;
font-size:30pt;
}

#comingsoon {
margin:0 auto;
}
```

I also placed this in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
```

I don't really understand what I have done wrong here.[image: As you can see, it doesn't fill the entire screen and it seems to duplicate the background underneath]

Comment: I tried it on my phone and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

There is no official solution for that, as all the mobile device doesn't have the same behaviour about it...

You can try that snippet in found one day that you need to add to your header of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
 setTimeout(function(){ 
  window.scrollTo(0, 1); 
 }, 1);
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to help, it made it worse on my HTC one

Answer (score 0):

try to set your `:root` element to a fixed position and then add a full width and height like like this

```
html {   
background: url(splash.png) no-repeat center center fixed;   
-webkit-background-size: cover;   
-moz-background-size: cover;   
-o-background-size: cover;   
background-size: cover; 
text-align:center;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
top;0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
overflow-y:scroll;/* or overfow-y:auto;*/
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow me to scroll. After adding the overflow-y:scroll it displayed the scrollbar but it didn't seem to detect that the content is larger than what can be displayed in the viewport.

Comment: can you please provide the css for the body?   if not try to add overlow on body